# C++ - gdb gives unexpected output when passing in a struct with std::string member

Tags: c++, gdb

Consider the following program, which I compile with `g++ -g myprog.cc`.

```
#include<iostream>

struct Context {
    //char *s; // version 1
    std::string s; // version 2
};

void f(Context);
void f(Context c) {}

int main(void) {
    Context c = Context();
    f(c);
}
```

Version 1 has a `char *` member, while version 2 replaces it with `std::string`.

Using gdb, I step through the code and get this:

> Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at myprog.cc:12
>   12      Context c = Context();
>   &ebsp;Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install libgcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64
>   (gdb) s
>   13      f(c);
>   (gdb) s
>   f (c=...) at myprog.cc:9
>   9   void f(Context c) {}
>   (gdb) s
>   main () at myprog.cc:14
>   14  }

Nothing wrong here.

If I step through version 2, I get:

> Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at myprog.cc:12
>   12      Context c = Context();
>   Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install libgcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64
>   (gdb) s
>   Context::Context (this=0x7fffffffe400) at myprog.cc:3
>   3   struct Context {
>   (gdb) s
>   main () at myprog.cc:13
>   13      f(c);
>   (gdb) s
>   Context::Context (this=0x7fffffffe410) at myprog.cc:3
>   3   struct Context {
>   (gdb) s
>   f (c=...) at myprog.cc:9
>   9   void f(Context c) {}
>   (gdb) s
>   Context::~Context (this=0x7fffffffe410, __in_chrg=) at myprog.cc:3
>   3   struct Context {
>   (gdb) s
>   Context::~Context (this=0x7fffffffe400, __in_chrg=) at myprog.cc:3
>   3   struct Context {
>   (gdb) s
>   main () at myprog.cc:14
>   14  }

Why is it that when I pass in a struct `Context` with the `std::string` member, I get the output `Context::Context (this=0x7fffffffe400)`?

Also, when I instantiate the struct, `this=0x7fffffffe400`. When I pass it in, `this=0x7fffffffe410`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You pass `c` by value to a function that doesn't do anything. So the compiler has to produce any visible effects of pass by value semantics. The compiler can't be sure that copying and then destroying the `string` has no consequences, so it does it. It can be sure that copying a `char *` and destroying the copy has no consequences, so it doesn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is you're seeing the compiler generated constructor, which is not generated for the struct with just a pointer, because there would be nothing to do in that constructor. For the struct with the `std::string` member, it likely calls `std::string`s constructor.

Since the constructor is a non-static member function, the `this=0x7fffffffe400` is the implicit 'this' pointer argument being passed in.